# Bash - How to make each menu selections in 1 line instead of multiple selections in 1 line

Tags: bash

Im making a tool script for my theme has 6 options:
1) Check theme update
2) Reinstall theme
3) Install font
4) Install wallpaper
5) Check tool update
6) Quit

Here is the code

```
clear
echo "==========================="
echo "Tool for theme"
echo "==========================="

function check_update {
echo "checking theme update"
}

function reinstall_theme {
echo "Reinstalling"
echo "==========================="
}

function font {
echo "Installing font"
}

function wall {
echo "Installing wallpaper"
}

function check_update_tool {
echo "Checking tool update"
}

all_done=0
while (( !all_done )); do
options=("Check theme update" "Reinstall theme" "Install font" "Install wallpaper" "Check tool update" "Quit")

echo "Choose an option: "
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
case $REPLY in
1) check_update; break ;;
2) reinstall_theme; break ;;
3) font; break ;;
4) wall; break ;;
5) check_update_tool; break ;;
6) all_done=1; break ;;
*) echo "Invalid option" ;;
esac
done
done

echo "Exiting"
sleep 2
```

But when I run it, the selections of menu mess up

```
==================
Tool for theme
==================
Choose an option:
1) Check theme update 2) Reinstall theme  3) Install font
4) Install Wallpaper     5) Check tool update      6) Quit
```

But what I want is

```
===============
Tool for theme
===============
Choose an option:
1) Check theme update
2) Reinstall theme
3) Install font
4) Install wallpaper
5) Check tool update
6) Quit
```

So how can I fix the menu?

Comment: Interesting, running that code (saved to `foo.sh`) on my system already produces your expected  output if run with a dot `. foo.sh`, but produces the messed up output if run without it `foo.sh`.

Comment: Im running script on MobileTerminal on jailbroken iPhone, since iOS also use UNIX

Comment: For more on this annoying shell behavior, along with a much worse kludge, see: [Select menu in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726958/select-menu-in-bash#)

Comment: Ok thanks, but a guy down here helped me

Comment: I just want one column so iPhone can display properly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the `COLUMNS` variable to limit the width of the display, e.g., if you set it to 12, it will format your example into a single column:

```
COLUMNS=12
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
case $REPLY in
1) check_update; break ;;
2) reinstall_theme; break ;;
3) font; break ;;
4) wall; break ;;
5) check_update_tool; break ;;
6) all_done=1; break ;;
*) echo "Invalid option" ;;
esac
```

produces

```
===========================
Tool for theme
===========================
Choose an option: 
1) Check theme update
2) Reinstall theme
3) Install font
4) Install wallpaper
5) Check tool update
6) Quit
#?
```

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) describes COLUMNS:

> Used by the **`select`** command to determine the terminal width when printing selection lists. Automatically set if the **`checkwinsize`** option is enabled (see [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)), or in an interactive shell upon receipt of a **`SIGWINCH`**.

Besides seeing the feature in the manual page, it helps to read the source code to get the complete story.  This variable is used in the [`select_query`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3007) function, with the comment

```
/* Print the elements of LIST, one per line, preceded by an index from 1 to
   LIST_LEN.  Then display PROMPT and wait for the user to enter a number.
   If the number is between 1 and LIST_LEN, return that selection.  If EOF
   is read, return a null string.  If a blank line is entered, or an invalid
   number is entered, the loop is executed again. */
```

and later, in the [`select_query` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n3028)

```
  t = get_string_value ("COLUMNS");
  COLS =  (t && *t) ? atoi (t) : 80;
```

If you give a *reasonable* value, `atoi` gives reasonable results (even zero in this case would be plausible, since that is *less* than 80 columns, and would be returned by `atoi` if you set `COLUMNS` to a nonnumeric value).  If there's no value, (i.e. `COLUMNS=""`), `bash` uses 80 columns.

Further reading:

- [atoi - convert a string to an integer](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)

  > The call atoi(str) shall be equivalent to:
  >   `(int) strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10)`
- [strtol, strtoll - convert a string to a long integer](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)

  > If no conversion could be performed, 0 shall be returned

Comment: Works, but the reason given isn't correct.  Experimenting with running the script with and without a leading dot: `. foo` *vs* `foo`, shows that `unset COLUMNS` causes the wrap, and **any** value for `COLUMNS`, i.e. `COLUMNS=1` or  `COLUMNS=1000`, or `COLUMNS=woof` produces the desired single column formatting.  This looks like a `bash` *bug*.

Comment: Perhaps a bug, but the manual page says `COLUMNS` is used to determine the width.

Comment: So, how wide is is `COLUMNS=woof`?

Comment: Scanning bug lists... [Debian's BTS for bash](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=both;dist=unstable;package=bash), doesn't seem to have it.  There's [a poor documentation report from 2011 upstream](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gnu.bash.bug/select$20COLUMNS/gnu.bash.bug/CYZddj_mJvA).

Comment: Interesting code info, but the underlying code is mainly only relevant if one is composing workarounds and kludges.  The code is not so relevant if it's a bug, as permitting illegal/silly values is just sloppy coding.  Simile: for widely used buggy programs like `bash` its immense userbase becomes to its nervous maintainers a mass of easily angered fanatics, [one that can turn against their masters for any small failure or change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Would_Be_King), which dread further enhances maintainer timidity.

Comment: @agc, re `"any" value`: it's not quite that bad, values like `40` or `80` behave as expected.  So: 's/any/almost all/.

Comment: In the `select_query` excerpt above, I'm not sure what COLS gets set to when `unset COLUMNS` happens.

Comment: Zero: an empty string is returned from `get_string_value`.